# Pulseaudio-dlna install on Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, pulseaudio, jessie-lite, repository

I've been working on a project that allows for streaming to the pi which is connected to a sound card and output to speakers. Recently, I've gotten an itch to make the system multi-room and want to keep the costs as low as possible. As such I've come into a few issues.

The goal is to install pulseaudio-dlna on a central raspberry pi, which will allow it to see UPnP devices on the network and create a pa sink for each UPnP device. I have another pi already setup as a UPnP device and can see it through Kinsky on iOS.

The issue I have run into is being able to install pulseaudio-Dlna on the raspberry pi. I've been banging my head on the keyboard for countless hours running into issue after issue. I am unable to add a ppa repo that is necessary for the dependencies of the project :

```
ppa:qos/pulseaudio-dlna
```

`sudo apt-add-repository` Cannot be found.

If I were able to add this repo it seems as though I won't have an issue installing and making the project but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Has anyone had any either installing pulseaudio-dlna or adding a ppa to the recent Jessie os?

Please forgive my lack of knowledge on the subject, I've either lost my ability to google from too many hours in front of a screen, or I've just lost the ability to read and understand what's in front of me.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am currently working on a setup that uses Ubuntu MATE, but I would prefer a working install for Raspbian Jessie Lite, as it would make things much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `git clone https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna.git` and then `cd pulseaudio-dlna` and then run `python setup.py install`. There was a couple of errors but I am still looking for a fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, setup.py is meant to be used with the make file and why you are getting errors. I found a working solution using Ubuntu mate, but now the package isn't working for me whatsoever.